# WTForms-Alchemy failing with ARRAY column types

Tags: arrays, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to use WTForms-Alchemy to quickly generate a form class version of all my SQLAlchemy model classes, and I'm running into a problem when trying to convert an SQLalchemy class with an ARRAY column type.  It throws an UnknownTypeException.

class CubeForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = datadb.Cube
       ....:

return this error

```
UnknownTypeException: Unknown type 'FLOAT[]' for column 'specres'
```

It seems WTForms-Alchemy, and WTForms does not support the ARRAY data type, and have a corresponding Field while SQLalchemy does support it.  What's the best way to deal with this? Is there a workaround for this issue, without having to subclass all the necessary WTForm components to build support for arrays?  I have many many columns of array datatype, mostly of floats and ints.

I'm just learning Flask-WTF, WTForms, WTForms-Alchemy and am currently trying to see what the advantages are.  Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that I forked the code and made the changes myself.  https://github.com/havok2063/wtforms-alchemy